# Not able create Temporary table in SQL Server using CI/CD pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to store my table data in temporary table so that it can be replaced if something goes wrong before or after deployment.
For this I want to create temporary table in Sql server using CD pipeline.
I have added "WinRM-SQL Server DB Deployment" task in my CD pipeline and entered an Inline SQL statement to create temporary table in database.

CD pipeline is running successfully but it doesn't create temporary table in database.I tested my sql query in sql editor and it's working fine .Following is my sql query.

```
USE TempDB
go
create Table #TempJobSatusTable (
jobID varchar(Max),
[name] varchar(Max),
[enabled] bit,
[date_created] datetime,
[date_modified] datetime
);
Insert Into #TempJobSatusTable
SELECT [job_id]      
 ,[name]
 ,[enabled]    
 ,[date_created]
 ,[date_modified]
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs_copy]
```

Comment: temp tables have a lifetime tied to the *session* that creates them. This will create a temp table but unless you keep the connection that runs it open, the table gets dropped again (and the table is only usable on that connection anyway)

Comment: Try to use Global Temp Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a temp table doesn't make it visible/accessible to all user sessions.

So if your CI/CD processes are creating the table from one database 'session' and then attempting to access it from another, it will likely not be visible.

If the table is required for deployments, perhaps it should be made permanent and simply truncated each time.